# how do i disable the past dates in a datepicker (calendar) in Jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am developing a booking system and i need to disable the past dates using  Jquery. i have downloaded the JqueryUI and trying to use the beforeshowday function to disable the past dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using de DatePicker you can restrict the date range as follows:

`$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });`

The `-20` means 20 days before, the `maxDate` is 1 month and 10 days from current day.

To avoid the user select any date before the current one use:

`$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });`

source:

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#entry-examples

**Sample**

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>datepicker demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>     
    <div id="datepicker"></div>          
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do i exactly add this code->   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0 });

Comment: In your `$(document).ready(function(){ })` function or in between `<script></script>` tags after your html code, `#datepicker` is the id of the element you're using as a datePicker, in the sample is a div: `<div id="datepicker"></div>`.

In other words wherever you're using the `datepicker()` function to convert an element to a date picker add the `{minDate: 0}`

Comment: naah, anyways thanks for marking the answer as accepted.